# SQL: Select object with condition based on ony-to-many relation

Tags: sql, relational-database, one-to-many

Assume, I have a `Person` table and a `Ball` table. Each `Ball` has a `color_id`, `mark` (integer) and belongs to a `Person` via `person_id`. `color_id` is something like "red", "blue", "green", etc...

Each `Person` may have any number of `Ball`s of each color (including 0):

- ()
- ('red')
- ('red', 'red')
- ('red', 'red', 'green')
- ('red', 'blue', 'green')
- ...

That's all valid

No I need to:

1. Get a list of `Person` which has at least one ball of defined colors and no other colors
2. Get a list of `Person` which has at least one ball of defined colors and no other colors with average `Ball` mark

Where "one ball of defined colors and no other colors" means, that if I choose "red" and "green" balls, I'm only interested in these people:

- ('red', 'green')
- ('red', 'green', 'green')
- ('red', 'red', 'green', 'green', 'green')
- ...

But not those:

- () # Not red, No green
- ('red') #No green
- ('green') #No red
- ('red', 'blue'), #No green, Has other color
- ('green', 'blue') #No red, Has other color
- ('green', 'red', 'blue') #Has other color

I can use MySQL or pgsql, but if there are any vendor-specific solution I don't mind seeing them too.

And there's also a posibility for application user to filter on a single color only:

- ('red')
- ('red', 'red')

or three or more colors

Comment: OK. Where are you stuck? What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Also, you are showing linear list of ball colors vs 1 row per person/ball/mark.  if that is the true case, can you better supply more accurate representation of sample data.